# Search Query with Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery

I just downloaded this code from a website. It is used for the infinite scroll. I am trying to use this for search query but does not work as I expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadData(pageLimit){
     $(".flash").show();
     $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html
            ('Loading <img src="image/ajax-loading.gif" />');
     var dataString = 'pageLimit='+ pageLimit;
     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "pageData.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){ 
            $(".flash").hide();
            $(".load_more_link").addClass('noneLink');
            $("#pageData").append(result);
      }
  });
}
  loadData('0');
</script>
```

I am thinking this way.

```
var dataString = 'pageLimit='+ pageLimit + 'search='+ SearchString;
```

and that **search** would be passed to pageData.php but it returned no value.

What could be the problem here?
Thanks.

Comment: it should be `var dataString = 'pageLimit='+ pageLimit + '&search='+ SearchString;`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have tried doing your suggestion but still doesn't work.

Comment: can you inspect the ajax using firebug/developer toolbar to see what is the params sent

Answer (score 0):

Your data string is wrong, different parameters has to be concatenated by `&`.

```
var dataString = 'pageLimit='+ pageLimit + '&search='+ SearchString;
```

But I would recommend passing the params as an object to `ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pageData.php",
    data: {
        pageLimit: pageLimit,
        search: SearchString
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){ 
        $(".flash").hide();
        $(".load_more_link").addClass('noneLink');
        $("#pageData").append(result);
    }
})
```

Comment: I have tried your recommendation using this

 var dataString = 'pageLimit='+ pageLimit + '&search='+ SearchString;

but it doesn't work. 

does it has something to do with:

 function loadData(pageLimit)

Comment: @Kyle where is `<pre>` coming from

Comment: <pre> was not included. I was trying to format my message. anyways, the code doesn't work. I don't know why.